# Is there any way to guess the value which generated by MD5 hashkey?

Tags: java

I have written java code to generate HashKey with MD5. Is there any tool or mechanism to find/guess the value which generated.

If so, please suggest me to make it more secure.

Comment: Brute-force throwing all combinations of your accepted input range til you get a match. So, unless you’re working from a not-too-large dataset of inputs, or tight input constraints, no it’s not really. It’s not encryption.

Comment: google `rainbow tables`

Comment: The whole point of a hash (as opposed to encryption) is that going from text to hash is easy, but going hash to text is hard (ideally, impossible in any practical sense, if it's for security). MD5 isn't secure, so you can actually create collisions... but for most reasonable purposes, the answer is no, you can't do that.

Comment: There are ways to get to the original input, but none of them is **guessing**.

Answer (score 4):

No, because MD5 is a hashing algorithm (all hashes are one-way), it's not an encryption algorithm (which can be two-way).

So, beside brute-force, the only chance you have are rainbow tables, that still cannot guarantee you to find the actual original value, since the possibile inputs are not finite.